# Would using this shortcut cause problems?

Tags: java

**CONTEXT**: I am making an infix calculator in Java, and am now on the point where I'm implementing unary plus and minus. An operator is unary if it comes in where a value is expected. This would be any of the following: at the start, after an operator or after an opening parenthesis.

**Relevant information**: (Assume what I say in this section works as intended...because it does.)

I read in a line (which is checked to be an equation beforehand), and store it as an array of strings, delimited by spaces, called `readin[]`.

When I encounter an "operator" (plus, minus, open paren, etc) in this equation, I push it to a stack called `ops`. Exceptions are for closing parenthesis, which forces a calculation to the last open parenthesis, and for these unary operators.

When I encounter a "value" (ie. a known, initialized variable, or a number), I push it to the values stack. All variables must start with a letter.

I cycle through each element in `readin[]`, keeping track with the value `i`, thus `i` is the current element, and `i-1` is the previous element in the array from what we are currently looking at.

With few exceptions, all math is done after interpreting the full equation.

**The Shortcut (Code)**:

```
if(readIn[i].charAt(0) == '-'){
 
             if(ops.empty() && values.empty()){
                    //is unary, set negative
             }
             else if( readIn[i-1].charAt(0) == ops.peek() ){
                    //is unary, set negative
             }
             //it isn't unary, continue onwards
}
```

**What it's Doing (Plain English):** It checks if we've encountered a minus sign, and if we did, it checks the following. If either of the following are true, then this minus sign is deemed "unary".

If the operator stack is empty, while the the values stack is also empty. If the previous element in the equation is on the operator stack, and thus is an operator.

**Why's it doing that?** Because if we didn't encounter a minus sign, then we definitely didn't encounter a unary minus sign.

If we don't have anything on the stacks, then we have either catastrophically failed somewhere, or we're at the beginning of the equation. As mentioned, an operator at the start is indicative of a unary operator. (However, I don't think the operator stack is too useful in determining this, so it may be a superfluous check.)

If the last element in the string array is an operator (including open parenthesis), then we are encountering this minus sign after an operator, which is also indicative of a unary operator.

By the way, "set negative" just flips a boolean value which modifies the next incoming value, so 5 consecutive minus signs ought to "add the negative" of the next value coming in, the same way 1 minus sign does so.

**The Question:** Are there any inherent problems that would arise from this code, based on the information given? Maybe ones that wouldn't result from standard equations.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. There is at least 1 problem with this solution. It's when you encounter an empty `ops` stack, but not an empty `values` stack, because it ends up checking both cases, if there is a `value` on the stack. And thus, it tries to peek in to an empty stack of operators. This obviously throws an error.

However, if you were to add a check for if the ops stack is empty, before trying to peek in and compare it, then that should work out.

This should also still fulfil the requirements in an infix calculator, as you won't ever have an empty ops stack if you are actually encountering the minus sign right after an operator (since it can't be used if you're encountering the minus sign, and not a number).....at least, not in any case that I can think of.